# Register event listener for the particular NHibernate Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

In my asp.net mvc application session factory is cached on application level. Than new session is created and closed on each request. 
Unfortunately logging service which is subscribed on PostUpdate, PostInsert events of the session factory requires current user id. Thus it is created in request scope. So it's possible that more than one instance of the logging service exists at the same time and listen events from the session factory/session (in case if more than one request is handled at the same time). As a result changes of one user will raise event on session factory which will be stored by all existing instances of the logger service.

The solution could be subscribing on session rather than on session factory. This will shrink scope of the logger service's dependencies to a single request's scope.

My questions is: Is there any way to register event listener for particular nhibernate session rather than for whole session factory?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. ISession interface does not expose EventListeners property but SessionImpl does. It's possible to cast session object to SessionImpl and assign required listeners.